# Sharepoint Customization

Tags: sharepoint-designer, navigation, global-navigation, design-manager

I customize the background and top navigation menu, once I close the sharepoint and open it the next day, the page is on its original way (like I've never customize them). The navigation bar was originally in horizontal position and now is in vertical position (something I never changes). On the other hand, now I cant see the get started option to try and customize the page again. How can I fix those?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint? Especially, is this for SharePoint Online? If so, are you using the Modern UI or the Classic UI?

Answer (score 1):

Try customization by using the SharePoint designer and check out the masterpage and do editing and then after changing checkin the master page and publish the masterpage.